# How to refer to the current object in a Django ModelForm?

Tags: python, django

I have two related models, `Company` and `Package`. Each company can have several packages, but only one `default_package`. Here are the models:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    default_package = models.OneToOneField(
        Package,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name='default_for_%(class)s')
```

and for `Package`,

```
class Package(TimeStampedModel):
    company = models.ForeignKey('lucy_web.Company')
```

I'm trying to make a generic `CreateView` and `UpdateView` for the company as follows:

```
class EditViewsMixin(DashboardAccessMixin, SuccessMessageMixin):
    model = Company
    success_url = reverse_lazy('dashboard:companies')
    form_class = CompanyForm


class CompanyCreate(EditViewsMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'companies/new.html'
    success_message = "Company '%(name)s' was created successfully"


class CompanyUpdate(EditViewsMixin, UpdateView):
    template_name = 'companies/edit.html'
    success_message = "Company '%(name)s' was updated successfully"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['packages'] = self.object.package_set.order_by('name')
        return context
```

The `CompanyForm` is similar to the following:

```
class CompanyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = [
            'name',
            'default_package',
        ]
```

The problem is that in this form, the `default_package` drop-down menu shows all packages, whereas I would like it to the packages in the `package_set` of the company under consideration, similar to what is done by referring to `self.object` in the view's `get_context_data` method.

In essence, I'd like to do something like this in the `CompanyForm`:

```
default_package = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    queryset=Package.objects.filter(company=self.instance)
)
```

However, this is not possible because `self` is not defined at this level. Is there some kind of method of the `ModelForm` like `get_queryset` for a specific field, in which I can define the queryset using `self.instance`?

Comment: Have you tried it? According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin.get_form_kwargs), the `ModelFormMixin`'s `get_form_kwargs` adds `self.object`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to do this by updating the field in the `ModelForm's` `__init__()` as follows:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['default_package'].queryset = Package.objects.filter(company=self.instance)
```

Comment: You can probably just do `self.instance.package_set`.